# How do I set default terminal to Terminator?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I'd like to have [Terminator](https://gnome-terminator.org/) replace the default terminal. For instance, when right-clicking inside a folder then selecting "open terminal", I'd like Terminator to open instead of the default.

How can I achieve this using Xubuntu?

Comment: Do not install terminator from Ubuntu software. Install it via `sudo apt update` `sudo apt install terminator`. This will make terminator a default terminal

Comment: @ToTenMilan is correct. Installing `terminator` from the command-line automatically makes it the default terminal--a behavior which I hate even though I like using terminator *selectively*, for certain things. So, here's how to UNset it from being the default once it makes itself the default without your permission: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096329/how-to-change-my-default-terminal-to-gnome-terminal-rather-than-terminator.

Answer (score 235):

From within a terminal, try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Select the desired terminal from the list of alternatives.

Comment: Does not work, although I get this:   
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode

Comment: I realize the comment above may not be very readable ... So: after I run the command, default terminal still shows up, eventhough terminator seems to be selected.  No difference after reboot.

Comment: Maybe your window manager is overriding the defaults.  What's your window manager?

Comment: windows manager is xfce

Comment: Also having same issue as Running Turtle.

Comment: Same issue (LXDE). Running `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` doesn't seem to be enough: `update-alternatives` switches to the new terminal emulator in manual mode, but the old one is still on auto mode. In the end, it's the old one that keeps starting. Something else is needed.

Comment: This worked for me fine on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: causes problems with GUI and gdm3 stops working while right clicking the terminator icon. Also, multiple instances come as multiple icons on dock.

Comment: What if our desired terminal doesn't show up in that select screen for a terminal like alacritty? I just built it from source on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: if you see an error like `There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper` when running the above command, you should create a symbolic link (replace /usr/bin/terminator with your terminal emulator):
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/terminator 1` and then run the posted command again.

Answer (score 119):

change Settings Manager >> Preferred Applications >> Utilities

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on Xubuntu 14.10.

Comment: worked for me for Linux Mint Rebecca

Comment: Worked ubuntu-mate as well

Comment: Note: This only works when running DEs/WMs like GNOME, Cinnamon, and KDE, and not if the user is running openbox for example. The GUI tools needed aren't always there.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu MATE when trying to set [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) as default terminal

Comment: works for xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Works for me in Linux Mint Tessa 19.1

Comment: Worked for me on Kali march 2020

Comment: This works for me... I'm using mint KDE

Comment: Easiest way, works with Mint 20.04

Comment: Works on `Ubuntu 21.04`. "Preferred Applications" has been renamed to "Default Applications". The application for my alacritty default is stated as `/usr/bin/alacritty "%s"`

Comment: On MX Linux, I had to additionally change the command of the shortcut `ctrl + alt + T`.

Comment: Works on Kali as well

Answer (score 63):

Copy-paste the following into your current terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

This modifies the [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/dconf?action=show&redirect=dconf) to make terminator the default program. You could also use dconf-editor (a GUI-based tool) to make changes to the dconf, as another answer has suggested. If you would like to learn and understand more about this topic, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it) may help you.

Comment: commands didn't work for me, but dconf-editor did on linux mint 17.

Comment: What does the second line do? Just running the first line worked for me.

Comment: For future readers: "DEPRECATED: This key is deprecated and ignored. The default terminal is handled in GIO."

Comment: @M.Reyes It works well for me, on Ubuntu Gnome 20.04. This changes the default terminal, e.g. the one that opens up when you CTRL+ALT+T or "Open In Terminal".

Comment: And obviously this works only for Gnome.

Comment: setting `exec-arg` to  `-x` differs from the typically desired configuration. The default for `x-terminal-emulator` is `-e`, which is also supported by `terminator`. So, most people will not want that second command.

Answer (score 35):

[devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) is right;

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

works. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used-in-unity) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/737233/455406), and some comments in [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/578293/455406).

Answer (score 21):

open dconf Editor and go to org > gnome > desktop > application > terminal and 
change gnome-terminal to terminator

Comment: This will only work if the user is running GNOME, or has the proper GNOME tools installed.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 running GNOME!

Comment: Depends on your DesktopEnvironment, if you have something other than GNOME, ie. cinnamon, choose that

Comment: > the entry is DEPRECATED because managed by GIO

Answer (score 6):

In xfce (e.g. on Arch Linux) you can change the parameter `TerminalEmulator`:

```
 TerminalEmulator=xfce4-terminal
```

to

```
TerminalEmulator=custom-TerminalEmulator
```

The next time you want to open a terminal window, xfce will ask you to choose an emulator. You can just pick `/usr/bin/terminator`.

## System Defaults

```
/etc/xdg/xfce4/helpers.rc
```

## User Defaults

```
/home/USER/.config/xfce4
```

Comment: Can confirm that for xfce (and xfce-related apps, such as thunar) copying the helpers.rc default file from /etc to ~/.config and changing the TerminalEmulator value to the desired one works. Tested for xfce to use gnome-terminal in Arch.

Comment: I already had `custom-TerminalEmulator` set but was still getting the message. I'm on i3 so maybe the mechanism to prompt me for my preference isn't configured. I just directly set my terminal `TerminalEmulator=kitty` in the user config and it works.

Answer (score -14):

The only way that worked for me was

1. Open nautilus or nemo as root user `gksudo nautilus`
2. Go to /usr/bin
3. Change name of your default terminal to any other name for exemple "orig_gnome-terminal"
4. rename your favorite terminal as "gnome-terminal"

Comment: to open Nautilus properly with root privileges, you have to run `gksudo nautilus`.

Comment: Probably the worst way to do it. If at all, you could create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`.