# set alacritty as default terminal emulator on Linux Mint 20.2 Xfce

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, alacritty

I've built alacritty from source according to this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-use-alacritty-terminal-emulator-in-linux/):

Now I'm struggling with making it my default terminal emulator.

a directory for alacritty on my machine is:

```
/home/master/alacritty
```

when I run:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/alacritty 50`

and

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`

I get to choose between:

```
Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /home/master/alacritty            50        auto mode
  1            /home/master/alacritty            50        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
```

It doesn't matter if I choose either 0 or 1, when I try to launch `x-terminal-emulator` through my keyboard shortcut, I receive a following error:

> Failed to launch shortcut"<Super>Return"
>
> Failed to execute child process "x-terminal-emulator" (Permission denied)

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and the guide that you used indicates that the entry register is located on this directory (in case that you didn't change it):

```
/usr/local/bin
```

so you need to run the following command with that directory:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/alacritty 50
```

after this it should set alacritty as default automatically and auto mode, you can check it with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

then to be able to open alacritty with the shortcut, in my case I just had to write this commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/local/bin/alacritty
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647630) helped me in the last part
Hope it works for you as well!

Comment: Thank you for the input. Hopefully, this will help someone else. I cannot verify if that solves my issue as I shifted to a different distro since I asked the question.

Comment: @punkuotukas, out of curiousity: what new distro it was?

Comment: @saulius2, manjaro KDE